# Fatal error in WooCommerce, how to find the source?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, fatal-error

My WooCommerce seems to log a fatal error on every page it seems and I can't find the source or what is going on. However, I have reasons to believe that it could prevent my WooCommerce webhooks from working.

The log is called:

`fatal-errors-2018-08-10-[long number here].log`

And the error is as follows:

`2018-08-10T02:04:16+00:00 CRITICAL Call to a member function get() on null`

This log doesn't tell me much. I assume `get()` is used in a invalid way. But I cannot seem to find what could be causing this. Isn't `null` where the source is supposed to be?

Comment: So that means that the method get() is used on something that should be an object, but it seems to be null instead… Nobody can help you more with the provided information. You should enable debug and look at the debug logs.

Comment: My debug logs won't give me any details on this issue. I am looking for a php related `get()` specifically right? not anything like `get_user_meta()` or anything? Is there no way to find the source or what file is doing this?

Comment: No clearly the **method** involved is `get()` (it is a method, but not a function), something like `$object->get('something');` where `$object` should be an instance of a class Object, but it's null in your case…